# Ubuntu root partition is filling up so fast

Tags: partitioning

Just a few days ago my Ubuntu server root partition has started filling up so fast. The server is the mail server and runs the DNS for the domain. I have deleted all the big files especially in the /var directory but this just buys me time. The biggest file I could find was that of amavis quarantined mails which were 1 GB. Any ideas what could be causing this?

```
XX@om-server:/var/lib/clamav# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              14G   11G  2.2G  84% /
udev                  2.4G   12K  2.4G   1% /dev
tmpfs                 967M   95M  873M  10% /run
none                  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                  2.4G     0  2.4G   0% /run/shm
//192.168.1.16/Volume_1/CS_Backup
                      1.8T 1001G  831G  55% /mnt/OSBU
/dev/sda5             202G   21G  172G  11% /home
/dev/sdb1             459G  315G  121G  73% /disk1
```

It eventually clears on its own- just as below, but I would like to know what causes this and why?

```
XX@om-server:~# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              14G  7.8G  5.4G  60% /
udev                  2.4G   12K  2.4G   1% /dev
tmpfs                 967M   95M  873M  10% /run
none                  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                  2.4G     0  2.4G   0% /run/shm
//192.168.1.16/Volume_1/CS_Backup
                      1.8T 1001G  831G  55% /mnt/OSBU
/dev/sda5             202G   21G  172G  11% /home
/dev/sdb1             459G  315G  121G  73% /disk1
```

Comment: 14G is bit too small. I would not go below 30G for /, especially if /boot is not separated.

You can use `du` to monitor the big files and directory, like `sudo du -h / | grep '[[:digit:]]G\b' | sort -n` lists all the thing that weight more than 1 GB

Comment: 14Gb is more than enough -depending on the tasks this server needs to do- . "Any ideas what could be causing this?" Nope question lacks information. Tell us what this server does. Tell us what those large files where. But start with checking /var/log/ for errorlogs that increase in size (and if so fix that error).

Comment: @Rinzwind. There are no error logs from the log directory. The server runs as the dns and mail server

Comment: When running mail server software it is not unusual that it might be infected with spambots, or be under a ddos. So I would check for that.